# Volume Integral of this set

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

I'm not sure about this exercise. Be:

$$E=\left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} : x\geq 0, y\geq 0, 0\leq z\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1\right\}$$

Find:

$$\int_{E} z\, \max\{x,y\}\: dx \, dy \, dz$$

My idea is that since $x,y\geq 0$, one of the two variables will be greater than the other in a section of the quadrant divided by the bisector and vice versa. For example, let's suppose that $x\geq y$, the  section of the volume would be something like:
$$\left\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R^3}  : 0\leq x\leq \infty, 0\leq y\leq x,0\leq z\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1\right\}$$
The volume of this would be:
$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^x\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1} zx\: dz\, dy\, dx$$ 
Then the volume of $E$ would be this volume plus the volume of the case where $y\geq x$, does this look correct to you?

Comment: You use the word volume for an integral that does not represent one, but otherwise the reasoning is correct.

Comment: Oh ok and thank you for the correction in terminology!

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer:**

The upper limit of integration for the $x$ variable doesn't actually go to infinity. Note that the bounds for $z$ imply an additional constraint on the range of $x$ and $y$:

$$\begin{align}
0\le z\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1
&\implies0\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1\\
&\implies1\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\\
&\implies\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le1\\
&\implies x^2+y^2\le1\\
&\implies0\le x\le1\land0\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}.\\
\end{align}$$

With the correct integration bounds for your triple integral, and strategically splitting up the integration intervals to eliminate the max functions, we find:

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\iiint_{E}\mathrm{d}^{3}v\,\left[z\max{\left(x,y\right)}\right]\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1}\mathrm{d}z\,z\max{\left(x,y\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1}\mathrm{d}z\,z\max{\left(x,y\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1}\mathrm{d}z\,z\max{\left(x,y\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1}\mathrm{d}z\,z\max{\left(x,y\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\int_{x}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1}\mathrm{d}z\,z\max{\left(x,y\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1}\mathrm{d}z\,z\max{\left(x,y\right)}\\
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{x}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1}\mathrm{d}z\,xz\\
&~~~~~+\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\int_{x}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1}\mathrm{d}z\,yz\\
&~~~~~+\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1}\mathrm{d}z\,xz.\\
\end{align}$$

Presumably you can take the helm from there?

Comment: Once i find that $0\le x\le1\land0\le y\le\sqrt{1-x^2}$ can't I just do the same thing for $y$ and sum the two integrals, instead of splitting up the integration intervals to eliminate the max function? (Since that step isn't that clear to me). I'd do something like  $0\le y\le1\land0\le \le\sqrt{1-y^2}$ and solve $$\int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}x\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1}\mathrm{d}z\,zx + \int_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\mathrm{d}y\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-1}\mathrm{d}z\,zy$$ I'd still distinguish the cases where $x>y$ and $y>x$